# equivalent of C# dictionary method "TryGetValue()" in Java map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I'm migrating a project from c# to java and i have problem with TryGetValue() method!

here is the c# code:

```
private static void _AddBadQualityChar (Dictionary<string,List<string>> badQualityChars, string charString, string badQualityChar)
        {
            List<string>        _badQualityChars;

            if (!badQualityChars.TryGetValue (charString, out _badQualityChars))
            {
                _badQualityChars = new List<string> ();
                badQualityChars [charString] = _badQualityChars;
            }

            _badQualityChars.Add (badQualityChar);
        }
```

I  don't know whats the equivalent of TryGetValue() method in java map all I could found is get() method which doesn't return Boolean ! how can I write this function in Java?

Comment: have you looked at the map class documentation? I found this with a 2 min google search: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-

Comment: @SelmanGenç How does that let you differentiate between the key not existing versus it existing with the value being what you supplied as the default value?

Comment: You can `get` from the `Map` but you cannot differentiate between the `Map` containing the key mapped to `null` and the `Map` not having a mapping at all. As Java doesn’t have “out parameters” there is no direct equivalent to the above. The best you can do is `containsKey` followed by `get` - which is sadly two lookups in the `Map`. So the question you need to answer is whether in your use case you care about the difference between the mapping being absent and being mapped to `null`.

Comment: oh so i have to check if it ```containskey``` and then get the associated value ```get``` but since java doesnt have out isnt that going to be just local ?

Comment: @Servy you pass a default value that will never actually exist in the dictionary (such as null or empty string), then you check the result. if result is equal to default value it means the key doesn't exist.

Comment: People here tend to down-vote questions if you don't appear to have done research first. For a question like this, it might help to note what documentation or other SO posts you've read through, and why the answers you found there don't pertain to your question.

Comment: @SelmanGenç That assumes that null or empty strings aren't valid values in the map.  There are contexts where it *is* a valid value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try to blindly copy and paste code between languages without learning at least the basics. In Java, rather than cloning your code, do this:

```java
Map<String, List<String>> badChars = new HashMap<>();
...
badChars.computeIfAbsent(key, __ -> new ArrayList<>())
  .add(badChar);
```

Your use case is literally [the example provided in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: Plus from me, but: 1. Two underscores for an unused variable needs explanation or avoidance. 2. I understand the argument against piecewise literal translation, but "Don't" could be formulated more mildly. Like when a foreigner talks your native language.

Comment: This is a good answer because it actually improves the code sample, and gets to the "real" solution they're looking for. As long as people are clear that `computerIfAbsent` is _not_ a general-purpose replacement for TryGetValue.

Comment: Well, thank you it solved my problem! ```Don't try to blindly copy and paste code between languages without learning at least the basics``` you are probably a senior while I'm still a freshman student and that's what I'm doing I'm still learning if am cloning code I wouldn't ask here where people can help me and probably explain ! reread ur answer and realize how  mean it is ! anyway thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

For the Java Map, the equivalent method call would be Map.containsKey(key) as seen here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-

Comment: Not directly equivalent as C# has out parameters. You need to call `containsKey` followed by `get`.

Comment: Agreed, I just assumed that he was looking for the way to get the boolean from the map, but yes, to do the whole call exactly like the C# version would need both.